# How to get an array object by searching for the value of an object attribute

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have an array with objects in the following format:

```
[ { _id: 5a60c891d4664d1c97b876e8, amountVotes: 0, title: 'A' },
  { _id: 5a60c891d4664d1c97b876e9, amountVotes: 0, title: 'B' },
  { _id: 5a60c891d4664d1c97b876ea, amountVotes: 0, title: 'C' },
  { _id: 5a60c891d4664d1c97b876eb, amountVotes: 0, title: 'D' } ]
```

I want to find an entry of this array by looking for its title value. For example, I want to find the object that has its title attribute set to 'C'.

Comment: Did you research anything? This is quite basic...

Comment: google is your friends, like filter function ...

Comment: `var obj = array.find(o => o.title == 'C'); obj.title == 'C'`